# CSS - change text color for overlapping background only (keeping text on white bg unchanged)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a CSS container that has a red overlay with dynamically assigned with using javascript.

The problem is I need to change the color of text which is overlapping red background to white while keeping the other part still black.

I found plenty of solutions to invert colors using `mix-blend-mode: difference` property, but this makes the non-overlapping text matching the color of the background which is not what I want.

Here is the closest example that I could achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/L9yw62p4/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing this part of your question:

> The problem is I need to change the color of text which is overlapping
> red background to white while keeping the other part still black.

If I understand correctly you have a piece of text that you wish to be coloured as absolute white (regardless of any blending) in the region where it's overlapping the `.bg` element background and to be coloured as black otherwise. I'm not perfectly sure then why in your code snippet you have the text coloured as `aqua` then.

Since you are not strictly dealing with colour blending but you want to replace the overlapping colour with a fixed one (white), the only solution I can come up with is just having two perfectly equal text lines. One of those will be nested inside the `.bg` element (and cropped) while the other one won't.

The colour driving the text based on the overlapping condition is set inside two css variables.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 1em;
  width: 300px;
  
  --overlapping: white;       /*text color when overlapping*/
  --nonoverlapping: black;    /*text color when non overlapping*/
}

.bg {
  background: #AD3435;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.nonoverlapping-text, .overlapping-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.nonoverlapping-text {
  color: var(--nonoverlapping);
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlapping-text {
  color: var(--overlapping);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="overlapping-text">ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nonoverlapping-text">ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC</div>
</div>
```

And this is a second version of the same approach that strips down the complexity to the bare minimum hiding the details by using pseudo-elements and data attributes:

```css
.masked{
  position: relative;  
  border: 1px solid black;  
  display: inline-block;  
  
  /*sets a static width instead to just fit to the content*/
  /*width: 300px;*/ 
}

.masked::before{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;  
  height: 100%;    
  
  /*here crops the content not fitting inside the filled region*/
  overflow: hidden; 
  /*but still preserving portion of text belonging to the clipped word*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  background: #AD3435;        
  width: var(--fill);
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: white;
}

.masked::after{  
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="masked" data-content="ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC" style="--fill:60%;"></div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="masked" data-content="THIS IS ANOTHER ONE HAVING SPACES" style="--fill:74%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this code:

```
.text {
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: aqua;
}
```

To:

```
.text {
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  color: aqua;
}
```

This will make 60% of the text black and the other 40% text color aqua.

Comment: Hey, I've used aqua as the opposite of the red for the mix-blend-mode: difference, but ideally I need to make this color: black, therefore if I set mix blend mode to darken with the color: black, unfortunately it does not work https://jsfiddle.net/f7k5tj4s/6/

Comment: @Rvfvl you want the 60% text color to be black which has a red background and the other text color to be aqua which has a white background right? So its solution is like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ystgjkhc/ I will also add the full code to my answer now.